# PostgreSQL Query Not Returning Data

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

I have 2 tables (`tabl1` and `tbl2`) and I want a query that joins `tbl2` to `tbl1` by matching its `col1id` and `col2id` so that the result set contains the `tbl1` data with the `name` column in `tbl2`.

The following query returns no data:

```
SELECT Date
   ,cast(tbl1.col1_id as varchar) AS "col1name"
   ,tbl2.name::varchar AS "tabl2name"
   ,tbl1.currency::money as "Avg currency"
   ,CASE WHEN rich IS NULL then 'Unknown'
         ELSE 'True' END AS "bank"
   ,CAST(Ranking AS FLOAT) / 18 + 1 AS "Rich Ranking"
   ,tbl1.Reviews as "Reviews"
 FROM tbl1 
  JOIN tbl2
    ON tbl1.col1id = tbl2.col2id
```

`tbl1.col1id` contains numbers like `3,999,999`

When I do a full right join, I am able to get the all the data from the 2 separate tables

I created a new table with certain names I wanted next to it.

I created a new table with values with the exact match of the `3,999,999` and I am getting no matches in the end so I thought types were at fault and I've been messing around with the data a bit and I'm stuck.

I am guessing the values are not the same type, so I did some extra work inputting it either as integer or varchar elsewhere and on the same query.
But the results returned as nothing but did not generate an error so I believe it's a type error on my end.

Comment: Step#1: remove all the casts. They serve no purpose, IMHO

Comment: The "money" type is horrible. Avoid it. To store numbers, store them unformatted (no commas); use `numeric` for monetary amounts.

Comment: If you're worries that it's a type issue, please paste the column name and type reported by \d tbl1 and \d tbl2 for col1id and col2id. If they are identical, please paste the output of the following 3 queries: `select count(distinct col1id) from tbl1`, `select count(distinct col2id) FROM tbl2`, `select count(distinct col_id) FROM (select col1id AS col_id FROM tbl1 UNION select col2id AS col_id FROM tbl2) AS u`

Answer (score 0):

If you just wanna to do what you describe in your post, better avoid unnecessary complexity. Does the following return anything?

```
SELECT tbl1.*, tbl2.name
FROM tbl1 
JOIN tbl2
ON tbl1.col1id = tbl2.col2id;
```

If nothing comes back I would first suggest to check if there are any tbl2.col2id that match tbl1.col1id at all.
You could do that easily by using a LEFT JOIN (atm by using JOIN you are using an INNER JOIN really). Your rowset would then contain all rows from tbl1 and have null values in tbl2.name if no join was possible.

Apart from that i would make sure that the datatypes of tbl1.col1id and tbl2.col2id are the same.